Mismatch in pytorch Hubber Loss calculation
So I have two matrices that I need to calculate the hubber loss, my predictions x and my labels y as follows:
their shapes return respectively

x.shape = torch.Size([16, 3])


y.shape = torch.Size([16, 3])

when I extract the zero values from the matrices with:
    Z = x[y!=0]
    Y = y[y!=0]

their shapes turn to torch.Size([47])  they lose one sample because it was null so their contents is as follows:
Z:
        tensor([-0.0458177179,  0.0794119537,  0.0132298730, 
        -0.0684378445,  0.0239270329, -0.0998859257,
        -0.0052077156, -0.0251933523,  0.0673011318, 
        -0.0612106398, -0.0158440936, -0.0163329616,
        -0.0501042753, -0.0480697751,  0.0425285585,
        -0.0132632162, -0.0011744332, -0.0364661291, 
        -0.0337458402, -0.0496659800,  0.0198419951, 
        -0.0582559109,  0.0249673352, -0.0003011823,         
        -0.0630656779, -0.0028106403, -0.0478336737,  
         0.0248849690, -0.0248453412, -0.0383186191, 
        -0.0145248026, -0.0016013812, -0.0033918321, 
        -0.0392261222, -0.0121430475, -0.0213719532, 
        -0.0376458839, -0.0001880229,  0.0371584892,  
         0.0006527156,  0.0143199209, -0.0159018263, 
        -0.0016747080, -0.1677681506, 
        -0.1180625483, -0.0595825985, -0.0515905097], grad_fn=<IndexBackward0>)

and
Y:
        tensor([35.7957916260, 21.6673698425,  9.7700004578, 
          34.3571853638, 22.8384342194, 12.3599996567,
          32.5878181458, 19.4447669983, 17.7210159302,
          34.8954925537, 21.9499092102, 12.2500000000,
          31.5930919647, 22.8414421082,  9.0699996948,
          33.4950599670, 22.7711448669, 10.4899997711,
          34.4383850098, 21.3011169434, 12.8400001526,
          36.1783103943, 20.6615600586, 10.4700002670,
          35.6059494019, 21.8775119781, 12.0799999237,
          32.5706367493, 25.7370777130, 10.4099998474,
          34.3967170715, 22.7617359161, 8.9700002670,
          35.6082382202, 22.0040664673,  9.6199998856,
          34.3121032715, 22.4560070038, 10.2299995422,
          34.3565788269, 20.7696933746, 10.2200002670,
          38.5010910034, 23.5856552124, 
          34.1491165161, 22.1938228607,  9.5699996948])

    loss = nn.functional.huber_loss(Z, Y)

when I calculate the loss from this I get the result tensor(22.3675804138, grad_fn=HuberLossBackward0)
but for my needs, I must calculate the loss from each of the three classes separately, and I do it as follows
for i in range(x.shape[1]):
            loss1 += nn.functional.huber_loss(x[y[:,i]!=0,i], y[y[:,i]!=0,i])
            
loss1 = loss1/x.shape[1]

first I take out any number that is zero (as done before) and then I select each class, and calculate the loss from the three classes sum them, and then I divide them by the number of classes, resulting in the loss tensor(22.1220340729, grad_fn=DivBackward0), the print of the classes contents is as follows:
class 0 X:
        tensor([-0.0458177179, -0.0684378445, -0.0052077156, -0.0612106398,
        -0.0501042753, -0.0132632162, -0.0337458402, -0.0582559109,
        -0.0630656779,  0.0248849690, -0.0145248026, -0.0392261222,
        -0.0376458839,  0.0006527156, -0.0016747080, -0.1180625483],
       grad_fn=<IndexBackward0>) 
class 0 Y:
       tensor([35.7957916260, 34.3571853638, 32.5878181458, 34.8954925537,
        31.5930919647, 33.4950599670, 34.4383850098, 36.1783103943,
        35.6059494019, 32.5706367493, 34.3967170715, 35.6082382202,
        34.3121032715, 34.3565788269, 38.5010910034, 34.1491165161])
class 1 X:
 tensor([ 0.0794119537,  0.0239270329, -0.0251933523, -0.0158440936,
        -0.0480697751, -0.0011744332, -0.0496659800,  0.0249673352,
        -0.0028106403, -0.0248453412, -0.0016013812, -0.0121430475,
        -0.0001880229,  0.0143199209, -0.1677681506, -0.0595825985],
       grad_fn=<IndexBackward0>) 
class 1 Y:
 tensor([21.6673698425, 22.8384342194, 19.4447669983, 21.9499092102,
        22.8414421082, 22.7711448669, 21.3011169434, 20.6615600586,
        21.8775119781, 25.7370777130, 22.7617359161, 22.0040664673,
        22.4560070038, 20.7696933746, 23.5856552124, 22.1938228607])
class 2 X:
 tensor([ 0.0132298730, -0.0998859257,  0.0673011318, -0.0163329616,
         0.0425285585, -0.0364661291,  0.0198419951, -0.0003011823,
        -0.0478336737, -0.0383186191, -0.0033918321, -0.0213719532,
         0.0371584892, -0.0159018263, -0.0515905097], 
         grad_fn=<IndexBackward0>) 
class 2 Y:
 tensor([ 9.7700004578, 12.3599996567, 17.7210159302, 12.2500000000,
         9.0699996948, 10.4899997711, 12.8400001526, 10.4700002670,
        12.0799999237, 10.4099998474,  8.9700002670,  9.6199998856,
        10.2299995422, 10.2200002670,  9.5699996948])

there is a difference of 0,2455463409 the losses even though all the numbers match, does anyone knows why this could be happening? Maybe some kind of rounding error? Or am I doing something wrong?

This seems slightly confusing, you are overwriting x by indexing therefore leading to a 1D vector, but then are accessing its shape first dimension size. Can you put the correct order of execution to reproduce this error?

@Ivan my bad, just corrected the mistake, I use z = x[y!=0], but I tough it would not look good on the question, corrected it now. But the execution order is the same as the question one now.

Yes but in that case the class-wise calculation you are doing with loss1 is not reproducible because it requires x and y (Z and Y have already been flattened and classes are indistinguishable). Please provide a reproducible example.

It seems like you're getting a different result because you're doing a different calculation: in the former you average across all elements in X and Y, in the latter you average across all classes meaning that elements are weighted differently in the average because not all classes have the same number of elements.

@DerekG You are absolutely right! I haven't thought about it, ty a lot, this helped solve my problem!

Glad it helped, I converted it an answer. Can you go ahead and accept that and/or close the post to help keep SO organized? Or just go ahead and delete the question if you'd prefer as it is likely to turn up in the wrong searches (title is not particularly related to the answer). Thanks!

You're getting a different result because you're doing a different calculation: in the former you average across all elements in X and Y, in the latter you average across all classes meaning that elements are weighted differently in the average because not all classes have the same number of elements.
